# Javascript not working in azure ad b2c custom sign-up page

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-ad-b2c

I have created custom signup page in azure ad b2c, But javascript is not working.

I have also enabled [Enable JavaScript enforcing page layout] option in property,

***Currently I am using userflow not custom policy

Custom page sample :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- saved from url=(0080)../assets/AzureBlue/selfAsserted.cshtml -->
<html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    
    <title>Sign up</title>

    
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <link href="https://demostorage.z11.web.core.windows.net/slate_gray/css/assets.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="https://demostorage.z11.web.core.windows.net/slate_gray/css/common.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="https://demostorage.z11.web.core.windows.net/slate_gray/css/selfasserted.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <style>
        .tnc-container {
            height: 100px; 
            overflow-y: scroll;
            text-align: left !important;
            border: 1px gray solid;
            padding: 5px;
            margin: 20px 0px 0px 0px;
        }

        .buttons #continue {
            float: none !important;
        }
    </style>

    <script>
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
            var checkbox = document.querySelector("input[type=checkbox]");
            checkbox.addEventListener( 'change', function(e) {
                var currentdate = new Date(); 
                var datetime = currentdate.getFullYear() + "/"
                                + (currentdate.getMonth()+1)  + "/" 
                                + currentdate.getDate() + " "  
                                + currentdate.getHours() + ":"  
                                + currentdate.getMinutes() + ":" 
                                + currentdate.getSeconds();

                this.value = datetime;
            });
        }, false);
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="container  self_asserted_container ">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <img alt="Company Logo" class="companyLogo" src="https://demostorage.z11.web.core.windows.net/assets/images/logo.svg">
                        <div id="api">
                        </div>
                        <div class="tnc-container">
                            <b>Terms and Conditions Sample Generator</b> <br>
Help protect your website and its users with clear and fair website terms and conditions. These terms and conditions for a website set out key issues such as acceptable use, privacy, cookies, registration and passwords, intellectual property, links to other sites, termination and disclaimers of responsibility. Terms and conditions are used and necessary to protect a website owner from liability of a user relying on the information or the goods provided from the site then suffering a loss.

Making your own terms and conditions for your website is hard, not impossible, to do. It can take a few hours to few days for a person with no legal background to make. But worry no more; we are here to help you out.

All you need to do is fill up the blank spaces and then you will receive an email with your personalized terms and conditions.
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


</body></html>
```

I have testing this javascript locally... Its working properly.

[image]

Using javascript function, I want to store current datetime on checkbox "Team of service consent" check

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: @juunas Not getting any error, But not working

Comment: Through the code you provided, I got some results userflow,it works, you mean not shown at all in your place,right?Could you provide sreenshots?

Comment: Have you tried adding `console.log` calls in your script to see what is happening?

Comment: Why don’t you just generate the dateTime on the server side with the custom policy dateTime claimstransformation? Your way is insecure.

Comment: @JasSuri-MSFT I don't know much about it custom policy... Custom policy is possible with custom sign up page ?? If yes can you please guide me for that.

Answer (score 1):

You Can are use a `CombinedSignUpAndSignIn` policy and you can display the Checkbox by
following process

Go to the User Flow properties.

1. Select `Page layout`.
2. Select 'Local account sign up page'.
3. Under `User Attributes`, find your attribute which should be a Boolean.
4. Set `User input type` to `CheckboxMultiSelect`.

Then go to the Languages menu within the User Flow.

1. Enable `Language Customisation`.
2. Download the English default language file for the `'Local account sign up page'`.
3. Look for the extension attribute name within `"LocalizedCollections"`.
4. Add a value as follows:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-language-customization#provide-a-list-of-values-by-using-localizedcollections

```
  "Items":[
{
     "Name":"Agree",
     "Value":"True"
}
```

Save your file and upload it as an override to the English localisation.
You should now see the checkbox and it will return `True` when selected, and `False` when not selected.

[image]

There is a [sample](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/sign-in-sign-up-versioned-tou) related to this which presents a checkbox, and writes the *version* of the TOU that was presented.

The TOU needs to be offered up by your [HTML customisation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-ui-customization), or you can write it in a `paragraph` [claim](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/claimsschema#userinputtype).

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling with this and initially thought maybe it was an issue with CORS on the storage account we're loading the page from. What it turned out to be is they broke JavaScript in "Page Layout Version" 2.1.21. I haven't by any means tested all the versions, but JavaScript seems to work on version 2.1.20 and below.

[image: page layout version]